# Making Linq operations to a database in Data Connections

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studo 2012 and SQLExpress.

I am attempting to make Linq operations to a database in Data Connections. The database is on a local server on my computer. It already shows up in the Server Explorer -> Data Connections pane.

How do I actually obtain the data source to make operations against it in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the Linq-to-SQL entity objects.  In Visual Studio:

1. Right click on your project and *Add Item*
2. Add the *LINQ to SQL Classes* under *Data*
3. Open the new *DataClasses.dbml* project file in VS
4. Drag database objects (tables, stored procedures) onto the pane
5. In your code, instantiate the *DataContext* class, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Get Started with Entity Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/data/ee712907

Answer (score 0):

You can add ADO.Net Entity model in your project by using wizard. It will create an edmx file which will have entities of your database. You can create the entity object and use those tables directly in your LINQ.